# IE won't respond to CSS or jquery

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, debugging, css

I'm apologizing up front for a question that is not particularly narrowed or beneficial to the greater community. It's now a matter of personal sanity to fix this issue.

I am working on a website and I created a social drawer. Basically you hover over a social media tab and it shifts left slightly. When you click it a drawer opens up with that SocMedia feed inside.

It works fine on FF, Chrome and Safari. Absolutely nothing happens in IE9! When I first created the drawer it worked fine in IE, but as I've continued to develop the site apparently I've got something conflicting with it. But it's not just a JS conflict because even the CSS hover functions are not working and, in fact, I am using minimal jQuery to accomplish this effect. CSS is doing most of the lifting.

Also, I realize CSS3 transitions don't work in IE and I'm not concerned about the smooth movement in IE.

Anyway, here's a link to the site. Once past the Age Gate you'll see the social drawer in the upper right corner underneath the Menu. Try it first in a non-IE browser to see how it should behave.

http://pearlvodkatest.com/

The HTML:

```
<div id="social_drawer">
<div id="twitter_drawer" class="drawer_pull"></div>
<div id="tw_drawer" class="drawer"> </div>
<div id="facebook_drawer" class="drawer_pull"></div>
<div id="fb_drawer" class="drawer"></div>
<div id="google_drawer" class="drawer_pull"></div>
<div id="gl_drawer" class="drawer"></div>
</div>
```

Here's my jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#facebook_drawer').click(function() {
$(this).toggleClass('open');
$('.drawer_pull').not(this).toggleClass('hidden');
$('#social_drawer').toggleClass('open');
$('#fb_drawer').toggleClass('open');
});
$('#twitter_drawer').click(function() {
$(this).toggleClass('open')
$('.drawer_pull').not(this).toggleClass('hidden');
$('#social_drawer').toggleClass('open');
$('#tw_drawer').toggleClass('open');
});
$('#google_drawer').click(function() {
$(this).toggleClass('open')
$('.drawer_pull').not(this).toggleClass('hidden');
$('#social_drawer').toggleClass('open');
$('#gl_drawer').toggleClass('open');
});
</script>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
#social_drawer {
width: 36px;
height: 450px;
background: url(images/tab_shadow.png) right top no-repeat;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1000;
right: -7px;
/*box-shadow: -10px 0 27px -13px #000000 inset;*/
padding-top: 25px;
transition: all 1s linear 0s;
-moz-transition: all 1s linear 0s;
-webkit-transition: all 1s linear 0s;
-o-transition: all 1s linear 0s;
overflow: hidden;
}
#social_drawer.open {
width: 375px;
box-shadow: none;
transition: all 1s linear 0s;
-moz-transition: all 1s linear 0s;
-webkit-transition: all 1s linear 0s;
-o-transition: all 1s linear 0s;
}
#social_drawer .drawer {
background: #fff;
width: 0px;
height: 400px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1000;
left: 29px;
right: auto;
box-shadow: 0px 0 21px -5px #000000 inset;
transition: all 1s linear 0s;
-moz-transition: all 1s linear 0s;
-webkit-transition: all 1s linear 0s;
-o-transition: all 1s linear 0s;
opacity: 0;
border: none;
}

#social_drawer #fb_drawer.drawer.open {
border: 3px solid #336699;
}
#social_drawer #tw_drawer.drawer.open {
border: 3px solid #6699cc;
}
#social_drawer #gl_drawer.drawer.open {
border: 3px solid #d94c2c;
}
#social_drawer .drawer.open {
left: auto;
right: 0;
transition: all 1s linear 0s;
-moz-transition: all 1s linear 0s;
-webkit-transition: all 1s linear 0s;
-o-transition: all 1s linear 0s;
display: block;
opacity:1;
width: 295px;
padding: 21px;
}
#social_drawer .drawer_pull {
width: 30px;
height: 31px;
transition: all .3s linear 0s;
-moz-transition: all .3s linear 0s;
-webkit-transition: all .3s linear 0s;
-o-transition: all .3s linear 0s;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 3px 0;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
z-index: 5000;
}
#social_drawer.open .drawer_pull.open {
left: 0;
width: 36px;
transition: all .3s linear 0s;
-moz-transition: all .3s linear 0s;
-webkit-transition: all .3s linear 0s;
-o-transition: all .3s linear 0s;
}
#social_drawer.open .drawer_pull.hidden {
float: right;
width: 30px;
margin-right: -30px;
transition: all .3s linear 0s;
-moz-transition: all .3s linear 0s;
-webkit-transition: all .3s linear 0s;
-o-transition: all .3s linear 0s;
opacity: 0;
}

#social_drawer .drawer_pull:hover {
width: 36px;
}
#facebook_drawer {
background:url(images/social/facebook_drawer.png) left no-repeat;
top: 60px;
}
#twitter_drawer {
background:url(images/social/twitter_drawer.png) left no-repeat;

}
#google_drawer {
background:url(images/social/google_drawer.png) left no-repeat;
top: 95px;
}
```

Initially I thought it was a z-index issue but I've tried a number of z-index combinations and even moved the social drawer in and out of different divs to no effect. I'm sure it's probably something minor I am just overlooking.

Someone smarter than me please help! My sanity is at stake. Thanks in advance. Let me know if I need to provide any more information.

Comment: $('nav').toggleClass('open'); what's nave is it a class? and should be $('.nav')

Comment: I created a fiddle, seems to work ok minus the transitions: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mMvn2/)

Comment: nav is the HTML5 tag <nav> and is not a class.

Comment: Hmm, it's definitely a conflict with the rest of the site then, I just can't find what's causing it. Any suggestions?

Comment: actually, nav doesn't need to be there. That's for something else.

Comment: What version(s) of IE???

Comment: Sorry, It doesn't work in IE9

Comment: okay. I was going to guess IE8, because you have an IE<9-specific block which loads html5.js, but that file gives a 404 error. Since IE8 doesn't work with HTMl5 tags, I guess that file is supposed to load an html5shiv type hack. If it doesn't load, then that would definitely break the page in IE8.

Comment: My next question is: Yes, you're in IE9, but are you certain that the browser isn't running in compatibility mode? Press F12 to get the Dev Tools, and check what the rendering mode is. If it's IE7 or IE8 compat mode then my previous comment about your broken IE8 javascript will apply.

Comment: No, it's running in IE9 standards mode.

Comment: Fair enough. I guess that's not the problem. However, you might still want to check that 404 error all the same.  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `z-index:-100;` from the BODY tag.  IE doesn't like negative z-index usually.

When I did this in the Developer Tool, your social icons behaved as designed.  I changed it to `z-index:0;`

Comment: You're my new hero. I knew it was probably something simple I just couldn't find it. Thanks SO Much!

Answer (score 1):

I think it is caused by the call to .Sortable() in line 49 in custom-js.js in your site. It causes an error in all browsers, but other browsers report an error then continue with the execution of your javascript while IE gets stuck there. If you want to use .sortable then it belongs to jquery UI which is not included in the referenced scripts.

Comment: Thanks, I also took care of this.